# Can I create a folder as a filter action in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, email-filter

Is there a built-in way or an addon that will allow the ability to create folders as a filter action?

I can move or copy to an existing folder but is there a way to make a folder in a specific location with a specific name based on previous parameters.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. This is with subaddressing in mind, by the way.

Comment: What are "previous parameters" ?